# Bootstrap 4: How Can I Set $font-size-base for Different Monitor Sizes using Responsive Font Sizing?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, bootstrap-4, font-size

I'm using the Bootstrap gem in my Ruby on Rails application (version 4.3.1). I recently found out about responsive font size functionality (rfs). It was just made available in version 4.3 according to the Bootstrap documentation.

[Bootstrap RFS Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#responsive-font-sizes)

[RFS Documentation from GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/rfs)

I could not find any documentation on how to implement this using the gem. Here is what I have done so far.

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

I have enabled rfs as follows.

```
$enable-responsive-font-sizes: true;
```

The default font size in `$font-size-base` is set to 1rem (16px, sort of).

I normally set the default font-size for different monitors in my stylesheet like this.

```
body, html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; }
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1239px) { body, html { font-size: 16px; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 1240px) and (max-width: 1999px) { body, html { font-size: 18px; } }
@media screen and (min-width: 2000px) { body, html { font-size: 20px; } }
```

From what I'm reading I should not have to do this anymore. With this new functionality, how does setting `$font-size-base` work? Should the value be set to the largest font-size desired (in my example 20px) or the smallest? I ask because Bootstrap started being mobile first in version 3. All the other default values I believe should work for my websites.

[Bootstrap Gem Variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss)

Since this is a new functionality, I have not found any information from anyone that has implemented this. It looks like a wonderful addition to Bootstrap. I can remove a lot of CSS code from my stylesheet once I understand how `$font-size-base` works with rfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is described in the [RFS repository](https://github.com/twbs/rfs#visualisation).

You set the biggest font size. It will be applied when the viewport is larger than 1200px. When the viewport is smaller, the font size is automatically rescaled. So, if you have the following code:

```
element { font-size: 20px; }
```

You have to replace it with:

```
element { font-size: font-size(20px); }
```

The implementation and default options can be found in the source code of RFS in bootstrap gem: [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/vendor/_rfs.scss).

Then, you do not have to use `$font-size-base`, use `$rfs-base-font-size` instead.

Comment: I’m used to seeing implementation info separate from the repository code. I saw the element code but I guess got lost somewhere. Your restatement is clearer. I will check code without expecting separate instructions going forward. I will do this and check your answer assuming it works. Thanks so much.

Comment: I finally got back to this after over a year. This works perfectly now. I just need to do some adjusting of html tags and I should be good to go.